# How do I delete until (and including) the 2nd occurrence of some character?

Tags: search, cursor-movement

Here's an example:

```javascript
console.log("basename of"path.basename(__filename))
console.log(path.dirname(__filename))
```

With my cursor on `path` in the first line, I've tried:

```
dt2)
```

but then my cursor jumped to the next line, at `__filename))`, which is last character of that line. I also Googled around and tried:

```
dt2/)<Enter>
```

Nothing happened, and I have to manually cancel the highlighting of search the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to delete **till** the second occurence:

```
d2t)
```

Which translates to:

```
d2t)

d    " Delete
  t  " till
 2   " second occurence of
   ) " )
```

Comment: Oh, I thought `dt2)` is more intuitive, thanks a lot!

Comment: @job_start `dt2)` translates to delete till the character `2`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The reason for the cursor movement is what you pointed out in that last comment: vim sees two commands. (1) `dt2`, which fails (assuming 2 is not in the line after the cursor). (2) `)`, which moves to the end of the "sentence"